# Getting error in exported csv file format using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have used below code to save data in csv format from my page. After saving i have got some extra line in my csv file . How i will remove it i need refer for this.

```
$connection=mysql_connect($host, $uname, $pass); 

echo mysql_error();

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or 
die("Database could not be selected"); 
$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

// Fetch Record from Database

$output = "";
$table = "tbl_record"; // Enter Your Table Name 
$sql = mysql_query("select * from $table");
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
    $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
    }
    $output .="\n";
}

// Download the file

$filename = "myFile.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
exit;

?>
```

here is the below screenshot for output value

[image: output csv file]

the red mark are unwanted line.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` an you'll be ok

Comment: if i use mysqli then i get this error msg...Call to undefined function mysqli_field_name()....what can i use here replacing anyone...please refer to me...Thanks for your comment

Comment: It is not just about adding a `i`. It is a completly different library : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: what i will use instead for mysql_field_name()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a warning that `mysql_*` is deprecated, dont use it. Use PDO, a quick fix will be

```
//Put on top
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

this will suppress the warnings, here is a good getting starting [read of PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

**Update**

To get the Fields Name in CSV using mysqli you will need to change this code

***Change this to***

```
// Get The Field Name
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
      $heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
      $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";
```

***This***

```
while ($finfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    $heading = $finfo->name;
    $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
```

**Enabling `mysqli_*`**

Check your php.ini for `extension=mysqli.so` or similar. it may be commented out using a # just uncomment it.

**Enabling PDO**

On a windows server you can add the following lines in your php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option --with-pdo-mysql In your php.ini, add the following lines

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: if i use mysqli then i get this error msg...Call to undefined function mysqli_field_name()....what can i use here replacing anyone...please refer to me...Thanks for your comment

Comment: use `mysqli_fetch_field( $result )` see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)

Comment: Thank you Saqueib...i have used it....unwanted extra line has been removed...but no field name in the csv file....only there is a name Array...

Answer (score 0):

You're using depricated functions and it's generating warning as you can see.

Use `error_reporting(0);` to turn of all error reporting.

I also advice not to use _mysql but use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)